# Firebase authentication - get data from other user's node but rules are set to ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry if the title was confusing, I'll do a better job explaining here.

I was reading up on the Firebase security documentation and came across this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart?authuser=0. Specifically I was looking at the "Sample Rules" -> "User" section which contained the following code:

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming I understand this correctly, you will only be able to read YOUR data under the "users" node, and nobody else's.

So in my app I need to retrieve some data about a "friend" (friend count, username, posts they've made, etc) which is stored under my "friend's" user id in the "users" node. So it looks like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "friend_uid": {
      "friend_count": 10,
      "username": "john",
      "posts": [
        "message": "post1"
      ],
      "age": 18,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this based on the permissions above? If this is such a common task (getting some basic information about your friend), then why do a lot of tutorials show that you should set the rules to what I pasted above?

How do developers get the data they need? Do they have 2 nodes, "users" and "private_users", where in "users" they store all of the public information for retrieval from anyone, and "private_users" is where they store all the private info about the user and set stricter read/write rules?

Or do they set database rules on the individual attributes like age, name, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You've basically given the answer yourself... You could either separate the data nodes and add an object with public data and one with private data, where both would have different rules for access.

For the public data node of a user, you of course wouldn't set the rules to allow complete public access when reading, but also limit it to users that are in the friend list.

Another option is to set rules on the individual properties, but this makes the rules quite big and harder to maintain, as every additional parameter needs to be added to the rules manually.

An additional thing I see when looking at your data is the missing data denormalisation. Each user object contains a list of messages/posts done by that user. So if you query a user in `users/UID`, you'd fetch the whole object including the possibly millions of posts/messages. So you should definitely exclude those from the user objects.

Comment: The option where you set the rules on individual properties also change the way you have to read your data because you would have to get each property seperate.

Comment: Right, if you are just allowed to ask for the public data which is put in individual properties, you'd have to fetch each one individually, as the query would fail if asked on the parent object. Therefore, wrapping the private and public data in sub-nodes would be better as it simplifies the rules and fetching the individual blocks